# How to convert .accdb to db

Tags: python, sqlite, ms-access

I am looking for **another** method to convert `.accdb` to `.db` without **using csv exporting** and separator method to create the new database. Do **Access** has built-in option to **export** files into `.db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access has built-in ODBC support.

You can use ODBC to export tables to SQLite. You do need to create the database first.